# NullPointerException Trouble using camera in android studio app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera2

Im trying to transmit phone's camera preview to a textureView in app. When i start the method i get the following error in logcat and the app crashes.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(int)' on a null object reference

This is the code.

```
try {
            //[0] Usually is the back cam but may need to play with it.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraActivity.this ,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            Log.d("asd","here");
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("asd","OOOOOPPPSs");
                return;
            }
            Log.d("asd","BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
            cameraId=cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            Log.d("asd","AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallbackForCamera, null);
        }catch (Exception a){
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the log output i get.

> 2022-10-19 12:56:06.227 11217-11217/com.example.testapp D/asd: here

> 2022-10-19 12:56:06.227 11217-11217/com.example.testapp D/asd: OOOOOPPPSs

If i bypass the permission check by changing the if statement to

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

The new log output i get becomes this

> 2022-10-19 12:47:19.959 10777-10777/com.example.testapp D/asd: here

> 2022-10-19 12:47:19.959 10777-10777/com.example.testapp D/asd: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

I have two questions, first; why does the permission check fail? (The app wont show popup to ask for permissions).

Second; I believe the code

```
cameraId=cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
```

Is somehow breaking the app, why is that and how can i fix it? Perhaps cameraManager is null?

This is how the cameraManager is assigned, i took this from a video i saw and it was working fine for that person but im not familiar with these concepts so any help is appriciated.

```
cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

EDIT: FOUND THE CAUSE AND FIX FOR MY OWN SITUATION, NOW RAN INTO ANOTHER QUESTION, CHECK MY FIRST ANSWER.

Comment: Have you enabled hardware acceleration?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. Camera manager could be null (if the device has no cameras), but the list of cameraIds could also be empty.

Comment: If you mean using hardware gpu for emulator, yes.

Comment: I tried to check if the list is empty with this. if (cameraManager.getCameraIdList() != null && cameraManager.getCameraIdList().isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("asd","LIST EMPTY!!!");
            } But isEmpty method can not be resolved. How do i check this?

Comment: No I mean the hardware acceleration in AndroidManifest. And also, some devices you need to instantiate camera manager in onResume() or onStart().

Comment: Oh, so doing it in onCreate() does not work for every device? I got the issue solved on my specific phone but if that's the case i ll have to look into that. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Yes or try instantiating TextureView on onResume instead. I can’t track this question anymore, you need to @ me here to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause; Like the idiot i am, i forgot to add camera permission request to the request line. Once this was added, the app would run perfectly fine. Although i have another question now; The first time i ran the app after adding the camera request, The permission request popped up on the screen and when i accepted it, the camera still wouldnt work for a few seconds then the app reset to the main activity by itself only then on the second try it would work normally. Why is that?

A bit more detail; the app consists of several activities, the main activity is basically empty only with a button and speech recognition, it directs you to the camera activity where everything camera related takes place.